# git, devscripts, debhelper on Travis CI

Tags: git, continuous-integration, fixed, travis-ci

I'm writing a tool that I want to test on Travis CI.

Can I assume that the packages

- devscripts
- debhelper
- git-core

are present on the CI environment my tests will run on ?

I actually just need **dch** and **git** to be honest.

I [just looked in thier cookbooks](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/master/ci_environment) and they don't seem to have what I need in there.

Is there any way to have what I need on the CI environment ?

Can [I install the packages automatically through travis.yml](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/) somehow ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved using **before_install** inside the yaml. That allowed me to specify any commands I wanted to run so I basically did:

```
language: perl
perl:
    - "5.16"
    - "5.14"
    - "5.12"
    - "5.10"


before_install:
   - sudo apt-get update  -qq
   - sudo apt-get install -qq libjson-xs-perl devscripts git-core debhelper
   - git config --global user.email "test@test.com"
   - git config --global user.name "Mr Test"
```